# ImportError: No module named cryptography

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography

I'm trying to run a script that is using "cryptography" module but when i run it says

```
No module named cryptography: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "....\Desktop\script.py", line 12, in <module>

    from cryptography import x509

ImportError: No module named cryptography
```

The module is correctly installed:

```
Package            Version
cryptography       3.4.8
```

I'm using:

- python 3.9
- windows 10
  *pip 21.2.4 from c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

Already tried to uninstall and install the module, already updated pip.

Any advice ?

Comment: What do you see if you run "python -m pip show cryptography" ? You may have multiple installations of Python on your system.

Comment: ...\Desktop>python -m pip show cryptography
Name: cryptography
Version: 3.4.8
Summary: cryptography is a package which provides cryptographic recipes and primitives to Python developers.
Home-page: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography
Author: The Python Cryptographic Authority and individual contributors
Author-email: cryptography-dev@python.org
License: BSD or Apache License, Version 2.0
Location: c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires: cffi
Required-by: paramiko


I got also Pythin2.7 installed (I needed it to install gmpy2 module)

Comment: Are you sure you're running the script with Python 3.9? Check that first, but if so, then must be something else... do you have a folder named `cryptography` in the same folder as your script?

Comment: ok i was missing the cryptography folder on script folder.

Comment: Happens to us all!

Comment: Thanks! 
Now the script need the Enum module to work, when i try to install it give so many syntax error (i had to install ez_setup before)

i also edit "certificate_transparency.py" from cryptography module because it had some error on syntax (found the correct code online)

This the script im tryng to run https://qualys.secure.force.com/articles/Knowledge/000002963